# c# MVC Request IsAuthenticated renderbody exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor

i have the following razor code to handle that only authenticated users can see the content. However i would like to bypass this if the user goes to Home/Login.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
@RenderBody()
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be done in your `_Layout` but in your controller/action with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute instead.

if you don't do it there, you're going to consistently see errors about `RenderBody` not being present on unauthenticated requests to other pages.

Comment: Good point, and the general practice. You should just be leveraging the attribute.

Comment: I have 100+ actions, i want them all to redirect to the login action if the user isn't [Authorize], is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You can globally apply the `AuthorizeAttribute` then apply the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` to the login/register action(s).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could do something like this:

```
@ {
    var action = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated || action == "Login")
        @RenderBody()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add controller or action aurhorize attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    @RenderBody()
}
```